# How to deal with dpkg error while installing Battle of Wesnoth?

Tags: installation, package-management, games

I get the following error while installing Battles of Wesnoth:

```
 **/var/cache/apt/archives/wesnoth-1.8-data_1%3a1.8.6-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

I tried to solve it by running `sudo apt get install -f`. But still I get the same message. I tried to run the game, put `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` but still no result. So please give me some advice on how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the archive is corrupted, 
delete that deb and run `sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo rm /var/cache/archives/filename.deb`

Comment: I initiated the commands, but couldn't find the archive

Comment: Replace file name.ded with filename in the error message, Alternatively try sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: still not working get the problem that setting dpkg was killed by a process call

Comment: Can you post exact error message

Comment: this can be closed.